# elasticsearch: how can I copy only one field to another index

Tags: elasticsearch, copy, field

I want to copy only one field from A index to B index,but I found there is no api can support.Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `source` filtering as described on [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) page to only copy the fields you want from the original index to the new index.